# Select from table where condition in another table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have four tables:

```
SELLER (ID, NAME)
CLIENT (ID, NAME)
SELLER_CLIENT (SELLER_ID, CLIENT_ID)
CLIENT_SOLD (CLIENT_ID, VALUE, DATE)
```

I need to write query to pick all Sellers which clients bought more that 500 (value) in selected date. Can anyone give me a little tip how can I do it or what to use?

My basic knowledge is that I need to use

```
SELECT * FROM SELLER WHERE...
```

EDIT
EXAMPLE
SELLER TABLE

```
ID | NAME
1 | s1
2 | s2
3 | s3
4 | s4
5 | s5
6 | s6
```

CLIENT TABLE

```
ID | NAME
1 | k1
2 | k2
3 | k3
4 | k4
5 | k5
6 | k6
```

CLIENT_SELLER TABLE

```
CLIENT_ID | SELLER_ID
1         | 2
2         | 3
3         | 3
4         | 1
5         | 6
6         | 6
```

CLIENT_SOLD

```
CLIENT_ID | VALUE | DATE
1 | 600 | 13.04.2015
2 | 360 | 22.02.2015
3 | 501 | 11.06.2015
4 | 800 | 09.01.2015
5 | 112 | 12.02.2015
6 | 98 | 08.02.2015
```

And all time query should return me sellers with id 2, 3, 1

Comment: How is `SELLER_CLIENT` related at all?

Comment: It tells which clients are related to sellers, e.g. seller s1 has clients c1, c5...  hope it little help

Comment: in CLIENT_SOLD table, you can't distinguish which client (of that seller_id) is that record reffered to? Am i right?

Comment: **Which** SQL is this? Tag it please.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? POstgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT s.id,s.name FROM CLIENT_SOLD cs
INNER JOIN SELLER_CLIENT sc 
ON cs.CLIENT_ID=sc.CLIENT_ID
INNER JOIN SELLER s
ON s.ID=sc.SELLER_ID 
WHERE cs.VALUE>500
AND cs.DATE=@DATE
```

Comment: where can I define c (client?) here?

Comment: @Patryk Why you even need client details?? You need the seller names who sold for value of more than 500 on the specific day,ryt?

Comment: Also, which SQL dialect is this where you can aggregate like that?

Comment: @Patryk If you want to get the sellers whose product clients have bought for a value more than 500, you need to have an id to map between CLIENT_SOLD and CLIENT Table(like Client_ID). Presently you are having only SELLER_ID, with which you can't make out which client bought the product.

Comment: Still, it works like first solution and don't need join, it just return me sellers with clients ids that sold more than 500 and I need that specific sellers which clients sold more than 500, i will make short example in first post

Comment: @Patryk For that you need to add the client_id in the CLIENT_SOLD Table, without that we are not able to distinguish between the client who sold or bought the product of that seller.

Comment: @Patryk It works like the first solution but always JOINS are faster than sub queries.

Comment: Thank you! Finally its answer :)

Comment: @Patryk, you can mark the answer as useful if it worked out for you.. It might help others.

Answer (score 2):

A simple correlated subquery to sum the value should do the job:

```
SELECT s.* FROM SELLER s 
WHERE ( SELECT SUM(Value) 
        FROM CLIENT_SOLD cs 
        WHERE cs.SELLER_ID = s.ID 
          AND cs.DATE = @date) > 500
```

Comment: Hm, it returns me SELLERS with clients ids that bought more that 500 and I want to get Sellers which clients (don't we need to use also SELLER_CLIENT table) bought more than 500 (sum). Thank you for response, it helped me a lot, and now i'm closer to solution.